# Administer the patient the drug? Administer the patient with the drug?

Tags: verbs, prepositions, vocabulary, medical

Does the verb “administer”, as in to give a drug, work like the verb “give” or like the verb “provide”?

Which of the following is better: 1 or 2?

> 1. Patients are administered the drug.

Like “Patients are given the drug”

> 2. Patients are administered with the drug.

Like “Hotel guests are provided with extra pillows.”

“patients are administered”
300,000 Google hits

"patients are administered with"
157,000 Google hits

Comment: I like German way more than English.

Comment: First: the numbers Google gives for hits of any expression in quotation marks can be very, *very*, ***very*** wrong. Look at the actual Google hits for *"patients are administered"*. Very few of them are followed by *"with"*.

Comment: And if you don't believe me about the numbers, consider the following: *patients are administered*: 300K hits; *patients are administered with*: 156K hits; *patients are administered the*: 136K hits; *patients are administered by*: 219K hits.

Answer (score 2):

Searching for usage using Google is problematic because Google doesn't index text the way you want it to. However, they do have a tool which does: [ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams).

[This ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=patients+are+administered%2Cpatients+are+administered+with&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpatients%20are%20administered%3B%2Cc0) shows no usage at all in published books for the phrase "patients are administered with", which is a fairly strong indication that nobody uses it at all.

[image]